# Using just one Custom Renderer for several ComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working through the "Providing a Custom Renderer" example [on this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). And now I wanted to create more than just one of these boxes. I did this by creating six renderer classes, one for each box.

And now for my question. Is it possible to just have one renderer class for all six boxes? For that purpose I tried to parse two variables to the constructor of the CustomBoxRenderer, like this.

```
public ComboBoxRenderer(ImageIcon[] currentImage, String[] currentString)
```

But due to how the programm seems to work, the currentImage array is null until a certain point, so I get a exception.

But let's assume this would work how I expected it to work, I still would have to create six seperate instances of the renderer for each box, which I'd like to avoid aswell.

I hope this is enough information, I could also provide my full code, but I think that'd be too much for this page here, if not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading correctly you could create a class that extends combobox and just adjust it so that it automatically uses your custom renderer, then all you have to is create a normal instance of your custom combobox and use it as normal except it will use your renderer without any hassle.

e.g. in your constructor you would just have this line

```
this.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer(currentImage, currentString));
```

Im unsure why you think you would need to create six instances as the renderer deals with each box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, but than I'd have to do `new ComboBoxRenderer` six times, because I'm always going to use another array for currentImage and currentString, but I guess it's not possible to just do it once because of the way the class works. Thanks for your help.